# Why didn't this ship defend itself in The Expanse S03E05?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-expanse

After watching S03E05, we can see Admiral Nguyen firing a nuclear missile and completly destroy the Jimenez ship, also from UNN.

What I was wondering is why don't we see the Jimenez defend itself with their defense guns (like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A4chstbereichschutzsystem_MANTIS)). We can see the Agatha King use those to protect against incoming missiles. Is it because of a difference of military class ships ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the second book, Caliban's War, Chapter 48:

> “Okay,” Holden said. “That was bad.”
>
> “What?” Avasarala said. “What was bad?”
>
> “One of the Earth ships just took three torpedo hits.”
>
> “It that a lot?”
>
> **“The PDCs** *(Point Defense Cannons)* **aren’t stopping them,” Naomi said. “Those UN torpedoes all have transponder codes that mark them as friends, so they’re sailing right through. They typically don’t expect to be getting shot at by other UN ships.”**